# Find if number is between two numbers in different fields in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

How would you format a query on a MySQL database via PHP to find if an IP address falls between two numbers in two different fields?

Numerical representation of IP address to find:

```
1265631252
```

Database format:

```
 IP FROM      IP TO       REGISTRY  ASSIGNED   CTRY CNTRY COUNTRY
"1265631232","1265893375","arin","1152835200","US","USA","United States"
"1265893376","1265958911","arin","1149120000","US","USA","United States"
"1265958912","1266024447","arin","1149120000","US","USA","United States"
"1266024448","1266089983","arin","1162425600","US","USA","United States"
```

Comment: maybe a "divide and conquer" approach might work better? split ip address into 4 fields of smallint (byte), put those fields in an index (this part is important), then query those fields in separate conditions like (or address 127.0.0.1, or adjust for a range): where (fld1>=127) and (fld1<=127) and (fld2>=0) and (fld2<=0) and (fld3>=0) and (fld3<=0) and (fld4>=1) and (fld4<=1) . Havent tried it, just an idea to try.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE 1265631252 BETWEEN `IP FROM` AND `IP TO`;
```

Will return the row(s) for which the supplied number is between `IP FROM` and `IP TO`.

Comment: In my testing (MySQL), doing similar IP address lookups, this "between" version was 2x as slow (160-170 msec) as this version (80-83 msec) "select * from your_table where ip_from <= 1265631252 and ip_to >= 1265631252;".  Primary key on ip_from and unique index built on ip_to were in place at the time of testing.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have the DWORD equivalent of the IP address then the [response from Jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367152/find-if-number-is-between-two-numbers-in-different-fields-in-a-mysql-database/2367167#2367167) will do the trick.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE 1265631252 BETWEEN `IP FROM` AND `IP TO`;
```

If you need to, before executing the query, calculate the DWORD equivalent of the ip address you can do the following.

Given an ip address `a` in the form `part1.part2.part3.part4` then the DWORD equivalent can be calculated with the formula:

```
dword(a) = ((a.part1 * 256 + a.part2) * 256 + a.part3) * 256 + a.part4
```

and then you can use `dword(a)` result in your SQL query.

Start with an IP address like `206.191.158.55`.

```
((206 * 256 + 191) * 256 + 158) * 256 + 55
```

The dword equivalent of the IP address will be the result. In this case `3468664375`.

See more about DWORD equivalent of ip addresses [here](http://www.pc-help.org/obscure.htm).

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this :

```
select *
from your_table
where ip_from <= '1265631252'
  and ip_to >= '1265631252'
```

i.e. get all the lines for which '`1265631252`' is between `ip_from` and `ip_to` ?