# range from 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this two Columns in a table:

```
numberStart | numberEnd
1001        | 1006
2000        | 2001
```

numberStart and numberEnd is range. If I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM range WHERE ('numberStart'  >= '1001' OR 'numberEnd' <= '1001');
```

It return all records, but should I do this :

```
SELECT * FROM range WHERE ('numberStart'  = '1001' OR 'numberEnd' = '1001');
```

Comment: Your table has _columns_, not _fields_.

Comment: Add some more sample table data, and the new expected result. (Formatted text here too.)

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Are you simply looking for `WHERE 1001 BETWEEN numberStart AND numberEnd`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner let say number 1003 should take the first row.

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2367167/5059727

Comment: You have two problems: 1) quotes (see my answer on this) and 2) logic (you want 1001 to be greater or equal to `numberStart` to be in that range, but rather than `numberStart <= 1001` you are trying `numberStart >= 1001` and `numberStart = 1001` which both make no sense). So you were looking for `SELECT * FROM range WHERE numberStart <= 1001 AND numberEnd >= 1001`, but using `BETWEEN` instead is both easier to write and read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with your quotes. Single quotes are for string literals. `'numberStart'` is a string, not a column. The DBMS compares `'n'` from `'numberStart'` with `'1'` from `'1001'` to compare the two.

Obviously `numberStart` is a column, so don't use quotes. And 1001 is a number, so don't use quotes either.

```
SELECT * 
FROM range
WHERE 1001 BETWEEN numberStart AND numberEnd
```